# I need to spoof the source IP of a packet

Tags: ip, nat, sip, spoofing, attack-vector

I'm running some tests for a security project and here is the scenario. I have a SIP server (SBC) that accepts calls from a list of IP addresses. 
I have a SIP INVITE packet and I want to send to that server with a spoofed source IP address.
I run wireshark and I see that I'm sending it correctly but my router changes the source IP that I spoofed to the public IP address and I can't find anyway to bypass this.
I don't care where the packet is being sent from and I don't care about getting any replies. I only want to know how to send this packet to the destination with this spoofed IP address that I choose. Please help!

Comment: Don't test this kind of thing on the Internet. You don't have enough control over the way the network behaves.

Answer (score 2):

> I run wireshark and I see that I'm sending it correctly but my router changes the source IP that I spoofed to the public IP address and I can't find anyway to bypass this.

Your NAT-enabled router is doing its job here.

If your router has a non-stock firmware like DD-WRT or OpenWRT it's probably possible with some `iptables` commands to tell your router not to NAT your packet from the LAN given certain conditions - especially if the router hardware is VLAN capable and you go through the trouble of setting it up.

Otherwise:

- It's probably easiest if you connect your cable or DSL modem directly to your computer and try this.  NAT can't get in the way in that case.
- If your router is running non-stock Linux firmware, you may be able to install the tools you are using to create the spoofed packets on the router itself and send from there directly from the WAN interface, bypassing NAT.
- Alternatively you could set up a PC with two NIC cards as a Linux-based router and definitely have any tool you need right there in front of the WAN or LAN interfaces.

I'm not sure what security mechanisms residential ISPs can/will have against spoofed IP datagrams but if they have any measures in place you will trip them and possibly catch attention/get you in trouble.  You should really set this up on a private air-gapped lab and test there.