# IP protocol source address

Tags: networking, ip

IP Packets contain source address and port.

My computer IP is let say 123.123.123.123.
Can I send an IP packet with source address 111.111.111.111 from my computer to a server?

If so, can the server verify that it was actually sent from different address?

Answer (score 0):

> Can I send an IP packet with source address 111.111.111.111 from my computer to a server?

**Technically** yes, but there is a high chance that it'll be filtered when entering your ISP's network, or when leaving the ISP's network for the Internet (in both cases your ISP knows that the address definitely doesn't belong to you).

Spoofing the source IP address is what allows DDoS amplification attacks to be performed, so in general network administrators do not like ISPs which lack such filtering. [IETF BCP 38](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2827.html) describes the recommended practices.

In reality, each ISP has different network configuration, but a large amount of them will block either packets pretending to come from a completely different network, or those pretending to come from another customer at the same ISP, or both.

There *are* ISPs which don't perform any source checks.

However, even then, such filtering could also happen *before* the packet even reaches your ISP – e.g. it is possible that the packet with fake source address could be dropped by your home router, and likewise on corporate / academic networks anti-spoofing is likely to be implemented. (And if the packet isn't filtered, it could be subject to [NAT](https://superuser.com/questions/1037255/i-need-to-spoof-the-source-ip-of-a-packet?rq=1).)

> If so, can the server verify that it was actually sent from different address?

Generally, no, not from the packet alone. (That's kind of the problem with DDoS reflection.)

However, even if the server receives your spoofed packet, you will not receive any replies back (it'll go to the real owner of that address), so protocols which require some form of "handshake" will simply get stuck – e.g. you won't be able to establish a TCP connection, so won't be able to make HTTP requests to IP-address-limited websites.

Protocols like TLS, SSH, or IPsec also include per-packet authentication (e.g. a [MAC tag](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2827.html)), making sure that you cannot send spoofed packets "in the middle" of an already established connection. (Though of course, TLS and SSH also encrypt data so you couldn't send anything useful without knowing the encryption key *anyway* – but "authentication only" modes like IPsec AH are sometimes used on semi-trusted networks.)

Comment: Okay, let's assume for a moment that packet filtering  and NAT translation does not exist. Server A has a connection with computer B, let's say it is UDP non-encrypted. Having known IP and port of both machines, packet format of their communication protocol and with enough luck, can I theoretically send a packet as server A to computer B and disrupt their connection? (for example send a packet which in their protocol means that the connection should be dropped)

Comment: Depends on the protocol, e.g. with TCP you can send a RST to terminate a connection (though I'm not entirely sure whether this requires also knowing the sequence number or not). Some protocols are designed to prevent that, others aren't.